# How to deploy a MSI that needs a per-machine parameter?

Tags: group-policy, deployment, sccm, msi

I'm developing a MSI package that installs my product. I do my best to follow all the [best practice](https://serverfault.com/questions/11670/the-corporate-benefits-of-using-msi-files/274609?r=SearchResults#274609), however, there is one thing I haven't found anywhere how to do best. I need to supply one parameter that is computer-specific, i.e. I'd like to run something like `msiexec.exe /I mypackage.msi MACHINESPECIFICPARAMETER="somerandomstuffhere"`.

My question is: how is this best implemented from deployment perspective, in order to work in large organizations? Does Group Policy or SCCM even support per-machine parameters (haven't been able to confirm/deny this)? The parameter in question can be stored e.g. in Active Directory as an attribute of that machine.

I know about transform files, but I myself would hate having to create a specific `.mst` file for each machine, so that's not a good option.

The parameter is not secret and can be stored pretty much anywhere, if that helps.

Many thanks to anyone willing to help!

Comment: SCCM and other real Configuration Management solutions provide this capability. Group Policy does not.

Comment: OK, thanks! So I could just proceed with my approach of having cmdline accept the value, and rely that 'serious' customers will be able to use that? Anyway, I'd accept it as the answer.